# AUC score of gridsearch cv of best_score_ is different from auc_roc_score from best model of gridsearch cv

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, gridsearchcv

I did a grid search on a logistic regression and set scoring to 'roc_auc'. The grid_clf1.best_score_ gave me an auc of 0.7557. After that I wanted to plot the ROC curve of the best model. The ROC curve I saw had an AUC of 0.50 I do not understand this at all.

I looked into the predicted probabilites and I saw that they were all 0.0 or 1.0. Hence, I think something went wrong here but I cannot find what it is.

My code is as follows for the grid search cv:

```
clf1 = Pipeline([('RS', RobustScaler()), ('LR', 
     LogisticRegression(random_state=1, solver='saga'))])

params = {'LR__C': np.logspace(-3, 0, 5),
      'LR__penalty': ['l1']}

grid_clf1 = GridSearchCV(clf1, params, scoring='roc_auc', cv = 5, 
      n_jobs=-1)

grid_clf1.fit(X_train, y_train)
grid_clf1.best_estimator_
grid_clf1.best_score_
```

So this gave an AUC of 0.7557 for the best model. 
Then if I calculate the AUC for the model myself:

```
y_pred_proba = grid_clf1.best_estimator_.predict_probas(X_test)[::,1]

print(roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_proba))
```

This gave me an AUC of 0.50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are two problems with your example code:

1. You compare ROC_AUC scores on different datasets. During fitting train set is used, and test set is used when `roc_auc_score` is called
2. Scoring with cross validation works slightly different than simple `roc_auc_score` function call. It can be expanded to `np.mean(cross_val_score(...))`

So, if take that into account you will get the same scoring values. You can use [the colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WD-MjAJXxZjtU6TovaGU5Ch6rnWA2fnO) as a reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The google colab notebook makes it very clear. I have still one question: is it normal that the difference between the cv result and the result on the test set is so big? Or should I do more folds to get them closer to each other?

Comment: Possibly your model is over fitted, so you should preprocess your data or try another model.

Comment: I just found out that I normalized the train data and I did not do it for the test data. Thanks anyways!